# How to perform a pivot() and write.parquet on each partition of pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe df as below:

```
key| date | val | col3
1 1     10     1
1     2     12     1
2     1     5      1
2     2     7      1
3     1     30     2
3     2     20     2
4     1     12     2
4     2     8      2
5     1     0      2
5     2     12     2
```

I want to:

```
1) df_pivot = df.groupBy(['date', 'col3']).pivot('key').sum('val')

2) df_pivot.write.parquet('location')
```

But my data can get really big with millions of unique keys and unique col3.
Is there any way where i do the above operations per partition of  col3? 
Eg: For partition where col3==1, do the pivot and write the parquet

Note: I do not want to use a for loop!

Comment: Interesting question but also not sure how useful it is! I wonder if this is necessary, what is the bigger problem you're solving by doing this?

Comment: @Dee Thanks for the comments. I need that data to be in the wide format for a particular library. Thus the pivot part. Thus i need to write the pivotted df as a parquet and later read it for use in that library.

Comment: @Dee The format required is; index: is the 'date' column, column names are the unique keys, the value in the columns will be of column 'val' .